# SharePoint 2013 is not supporting SSRS 2012 for SharePoint, despite installed SQL 2012 Addin for SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

I have installed SharePoint 2013 farm on Windows Server 2012 am and using SQL Server 2012 SP1 for database on another Windows 2012 Server.

I want to install reporting Services for SQL Server 2012. I followed the link http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg426282.aspx, downloaded the Reporting service SQL Server Add in SP1 and successfully installed on my SharePoint app server.

i check the reporting services is running fine after installation.

On checking the General Application Setting Reporting Service is appeared showing "SQL Server Reporting Services (2008 and 2008 R2)". I need to install Reporting service for 2012!
when i tried to add report server Web service URL the page shows me following message "You can integrate this SharePoint environment with an instance of SQL Server 2008 R2 Reporting Services or SQL Server 2008 Reporting Services to enable full reporting functionality"

I have installed and uninstalled the add in several times but the problem still persist.

anyone please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now it's working! I will share my finding:

If we have SSRS 2008 or 2008 R2, we have to run the SQL Reporting Services Configuration followed by SharePoint Settings for the SSRS, which is available under General Application Settings.

In case your reporting server is on SQL SERVER 2012 you don't need do any configuration in Reporting Services Configuration, you can straight away deploy and configure your reports :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove it as there is no need to download a stand alon installation. On the SQL server installation disk for 2012 it contains a feature that inclueds ssrs, ssas and ssis.

follow this instead:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219067.aspx

**EDIT**

step by step guide:

http://get-sharepoint.com/2013/06/sql-2012-ssrs-integration-with-sharepoint/

**EDIT**

found this:

> I think you mean you installed Reporting Services 2012 SP1 and chose
>   the SharePoint Integrated Mode.. Also, if you go to Central
>   Administration > General Application Settings you will notice "SQL
>   Server Reporting Services (2008 and 2008 R2) " **this is not used to
>   configure Reporting Services Integration with SQL 2012 SP1**...

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bb42c91b-9195-4cf5-9b99-af48ba79d873/sharepoint-2013-and-sql-2012-sp1-reporting-services-integration-failure?forum=sharepointadmin

> If you installed Reporting Services after you installed SharePoint
>   then you should be able to check the installation by running the
>   following PowerShell command by opening the SharePoint 2013 Management
>   Shell and pasting the command into the window.  It will return the
>   status of SQL Server Reporting Services.

```
get-spserviceinstance -all |where {$_.TypeName -like "SQL Server Reporting*"}
```

looks like your fine ;) , just follow the steps within the first two links iv given above!

from my understanding is that sharepoint is picking up the default sql server database engine instance that is installed when you install sharepoint which is sql 2008!

**EDIT**

you sure your following the steps ;)

so you have sql server 2012 installed on windwos server 2012. You then went on to install ssrs feature from sql server instllation.

have you ran powerpivot for 2013 configuation?

click start -> down arrow -> under microsoft sql server 2012 click on -> reporting services configuration manager.

make sure its running!

what mode is it running under? as i belive it should be native mode?

also goto the 2008 one and disable that service. Sharepoint should pickup the correct version

Comment: Hi Ali,Thanks for your response,but i tried that too with same result do i need to install the addin before sharepoint installation?

Comment: no it doesnt matter, you sure your running SQL 2012 installation disk?

Comment: Yes,its Microsoft SQL Server 2012 SP1

Comment: also Checked the version of the addin too its 11.1.3000.0,the problem is that on add in installation the reporting services are successfully getting installed but for 2008 and 2008R2 :(

Comment: just ammended my answer!

Comment: whats funny is iv just setup ssrs 2 weeks ago but never checked up on the version. Aslong as your content db farm db are on sql 2012 and u used sql 2012 install disk then there is nothing to worry! good luck :) , it was a pain to setup btw but works great once its done :)

Comment: yes its working fine for if the report server is on 2008 or 2008 R2 but my report server is on SQl Server 2012 and when i am trying to add the report server to Report Service under Genral Application Setting it is throwing an error.it shows following message "
You can integrate this SharePoint environment with an instance of SQL Server 2008 R2 Reporting Services or SQL Server 2008 Reporting Services to enable full reporting functionality. 
 
Use this page to configure integration settings for SQL Server Reporting Services. 
"

Comment: just ammended my answer