# How to have Report Viewer Web Part for SP 2013 and SQL Reports 2008 R2

Tags: 2013, sql-server, reporting-services

I am trying to display a SQL Reports 2008 R2 report in SharePoint 2013.

I am confused because I can not find a web part for SharePoint 2013 that can display a SQL Server 2008 R2 Report.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you installed Reporting Services Add-in for SharePoint products?

Comment: No, I am confused. Only the one for SQL 2012 targets SharePoint 2013 if I am correct

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492257(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/95712/sharepoint-2013-is-not-supporting-ssrs-2012-for-sharepoint-despite-installed-sq

Answer (score 0):

I was going to comment first, but I don't have enough reputation yet.

Yes according to your link it is not supported. Only SSRS 2012 SP1 add in is supported for sharepoint 2013.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492257(v=sql.110).aspx

However depending on the version of your SSRS instance and if it is in native or integrated mode it might be posssible. I say this because if you create an ssrs project in sql 2012 visual studio the version is "2008 R2 or later", even though you are deploying to a 2012 SSRS engine. If you are deploying your 2008 R2 report to a SSRS 2012 server in integrated mode then you should have no problem installing the SSRS 2012 SP1 add in, web part, etc. If you have a 2008 R2 SSRS native mode instance let's say, then you could try this solution.  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/b2ea4860-0017-4c19-b6ae-7c3769b40640/sharepoint-2013-and-native-mode-ssrs-web-parts?forum=sharepointgeneral